# Check if app available on Android Market

Tags: java, android, servlets, google-play

Given an Android application's id/package name, how can I check programatically if the application is available on the Android Market?

For example:

com.rovio.angrybirds is available, where as com.random.app.ibuilt is not

I am planning on having this check be performed either from an Android application or from a Java Servlet.

Thank you,

PS: I took a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ , but I was wondering if there was any simpler way to checking

Comment: Be careful though and read the fine print of the license agreement with Google Market, this may be a violation of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to open the details page for the app - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirds.

If the app [doesn't](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.random.app.ibuilt) exist, you get this:

[image]

It's perhaps not ideal, but you should be able to parse the returned HTML to determine that the app doesn't exist.

Comment: Hopefully this is actually a 404 page, and parsing wouldn't be required, just check the headers.  Haven't checked though :)

Comment: I'm not convinced it is unfortunately, but the HTML looks reasonably well structured so parsing should hopefully be relatively straight-forward. Though of course is subject to change without notice.

Comment: @Jay - Yes, it seems it is a 404 page. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind, since this is out of your control, if the API decides to change something your code assumes today (ex, HTTP Code 404), it might break your programatic check.

Answer (score 2):

> Given an Android application's id/package name, how can I check programatically if the application is available on the Android Market?

There is no documented and supported means to do this.

Answer (score 2):

While the html parsing solution by @RivieeaKid works, I found that this might be a more durable and correct solution. Please make sure to use the 'https' prefix (not plain 'http') to avoid redirects.

```
/**
 * Checks if an app with the specified package name is available on Google Play.
 * Must be invoked from a separate thread in Android.
 *
 * @param packageName the name of package, e.g. "com.domain.random_app"
 * @return {@code true} if available, {@code false} otherwise
 * @throws IOException if a network exception occurs
 */
private boolean availableOnGooglePlay(final String packageName)
        throws IOException
{
    final URL url = new URL("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpURLConnection.connect();
    final int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(TAG, "responseCode for " + packageName + ": " + responseCode);
    if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) // code 200
    {
        return true;
    }
    else // this will be HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND or code 404 if the package is not found
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```