# Programmatically check availability of Application from library

Tags: android, google-play

There is one application that we have using a library of ours, so no problems there.  However, there is a request of others that want to use our library.  There are certain restrictions on our library (such as connect with certain manufacture devices, and USB-Host mode for instance).  The user of the library will not be putting in those restrictions since they want their app to work even if not compatible with the library inside of it.

So, how do we programmatically check whether or not our application is available on the Google Play Store?  Essentially this was my thought on letting them know in the library whether or not the device qualifies.  Then they can let the user know that their device doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Android doesn't support this for a number of reasons, but some people have worked on some work-arounds. Check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516887/check-if-app-available-on-android-market

Comment: Yeah, checking against the URL was one thing that I was thinking of attempting.  Not the most ideal, but it should do the job if that is the only way to attempt the check.

Comment: It really is kind of unfortunate that you can't at least ask the market if it is there, especially with all of the new Google Play API stuff. I understand forbidding interaction past pings in the market, well anywho, for now that seems the best hack together.